# setting state before a return always fails because it is not finished react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've found various questions similar to this but I could never get the solution to work, I'm not sure how to approach my problem.

I have a fairly large grid (2D array) being generated in which I map it out and insert a *node* component. This process is done within a Grid component as it is generating this Grid.

Breaking down my bug:

I had it before when ComponentDidMount it would calculate the width and height of the array and create the grid, which worked in creating the grid, although, best practises tell me that you don't set state within ComponentDidMount unless its an HTTP call for data.

Within the `render() { return () }` I had a if statement that checked if the state was undefined and render some sort of message such as `initalizing grid` and if the state of the array was not undefined it would render `DisplayGrid()`. Even after the grid was render, the if did not fire.

The bottom line here is I have no idea how to properly delay my render before the state is loaded OR have my render reload once the state *is* set.

I tried using a call back within `GenerateGrid()` to call `DisplayGrid()` and have my main component return call `GenerateGrid()` but the ended in an endless loop or after tweaking, once again, a undefined map once displaygrid was called.

Here is a broken example of the full component:

```
export default class Grid extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      nodeSize : 50,
      nodeArray : [],
    }
  }
  // Generate a dynamic grid
  GenerateGrid = () => {
    const newNodeArray = [];
    const nodeSize = this.state.nodeSize;

    // get window inner hieght + width based on browser size (onstart) and remove 50px from height due to header
    let screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    let screenHieght = window.innerHeight - 50;

    // get max amount of nodes based on node size
    const whNodes =  [Math.trunc(screenWidth / nodeSize),Math.trunc(screenHieght / nodeSize)];

    // begin creating the 2D array representing the grid
    for (let row = 0; row < whNodes[0]; row++) { 
      const newRow = []; // initialize 1D array
      for (let col = 0; col < whNodes[1]; col++) {
        newRow.push([]); // initalize 2D array
      }
      newNodeArray.push(newRow); // push into newNodeArray
    } 
    this.setState(
      {nodeArray : newNodeArray}, // set nodeArray state with the new 2D array based on viewport.
      // this.DisplayNodes()  // call function once completed if I used this GenerateGrid method within the return render (does not work)
    );
  }
  DisplayNodes = () => {
    const {nodeArray} = this.state.nodeArray; // get the node array from state
    console.log(nodeArray); // the bug is here. Always undefined.
    return (
      <div id="grid">
        {nodeArray.map((row, rowIdx) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {row.map((node,nodeIdx) => <Node/>)}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
  render() {
    const {nodeArray} = this.state.nodeArray; // get the node array from state
    console.log(nodeArray);
    return (
      <div id="grid-wrapper">
        {this.GenerateGrid()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Again I only ever got the grid to generate under componentDidMount but then I can never display it.

Here is how I tried to handle this with the setState call back method:

Within the GenerateGrid seState:

```
this.setState(
  {nodeArray : newNodeArray}, // set nodeArray state with the new 2D array based on viewport.
  this.DisplayNodes
);
```

and then within the render of the main component:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="grid-wrapper">
        {this.GenerateGrid()} //create a infinte setState loop
      </div>
    )
  }
```

This also spits out an error that map is undefined (aka the state isn't set before the `DisplayGrid` method is called.

Comment: This is an issue with setState being async in nature, therefore your use of a callback function in your setState is the (probably) the correct way to do it (or using componentDidUpdate but i think that is overkill in this situation)

Comment: @Willman.Codes I've updated my question to include the callback method, which still causes the same bug for me. I figured that would be the correct solution but apparently not :/

Comment: You should note that your variable that you're looking for your array in will always be undefined. `const {nodeArray} = this.state.nodeArray; ` is expecting an object value called 'nodeArray' inside the 'nodeArray' key in state. I think what you meant to do is `const {nodeArray} = this.state`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't call `setState` in your `render` function. 
What you can try is to return `newNodeArray` from `GenerateGrid` and pass it to `DisplayNodes`:

```
GenerateGrid = () => {
    const newNodeArray = [];
    const nodeSize = this.state.nodeSize;

    // get window inner hieght + width based on browser size (onstart) and remove 50px from height due to header
    let screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    let screenHieght = window.innerHeight - 50;

    // get max amount of nodes based on node size
    const whNodes = [
      Math.trunc(screenWidth / nodeSize),
      Math.trunc(screenHieght / nodeSize)
    ];

    // begin creating the 2D array representing the grid
    for (let row = 0; row < whNodes[0]; row++) {
      const newRow = []; // initialize 1D array
      for (let col = 0; col < whNodes[1]; col++) {
        newRow.push([]); // initalize 2D array
      }
      newNodeArray.push(newRow); // push into newNodeArray
    }
    return this.DisplayNodes(newNodeArray);
  };
```

And then use that calculated value instead of value from state:

```
DisplayNodes = nodeArray => {
....
```

Comment: that actually worked quite well. 

Although, how would I save it to the state after I've generated it? (lets say I needed there for something else in the future)

Answer (score 1):

No bug. Your destructuring in both your `DisplayNodes()` function and your `render()` function are both incorrect. You're looking for an object inside of your array instead of the array. Change each of your `const {nodeArray} = this.state.nodeArray` to just `const {nodeArray} = this.state` and I think you'll be good.

Comment: This was actually part of the bug which solved some of the problems, although, it didn't fully fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from problems that were already pointed out (wrong destructuring and setstate in render) what is important here is to understand how to manage data in react

`render()` should only be rendering data (returning elements) from state and props. Modyfing your data should happen outside of render. It's not clear to me what is `GenerateArray` doing in this example. Should it be ran only once when component mounts or do you want it to run every single render?

> I had it before when ComponentDidMount it would calculate the width and height of the array and create the grid, which worked in creating the grid, although, best practises tell me that you don't set state within ComponentDidMount unless its an HTTP call for data

You are basically just formatting your data, or calculating initial state here. This logic should go in `constructor`. Put the result of your calculation in `this.state = { nodeArray: result, ... }`

Then you should ask yourself, "when should this logic run again"? Result of `GenerateGrid` depends on `nodeSize` and screen dimensions. Clearly `nodeSize` here never changes, it might as well be a constant 50. `screenWidth` and `screenHeight` doesn't change either, so I suppose you should never re-run this logic after you initially made these calculations. In this case you should take it away from render. If you would want your grid to re-calculate when screen dimensions change, you would have to create listener for window onResize event and update new `screenHeight` and `screenWidth` in state and then put run this formatting logic in every render

It is, again, very important to remember that `render` should only be rendering data from state and props, while lifecycle methods and listeners you create should be changing state that is used during render